# Select item from xml to apply it on a button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable

Here's what I have :

Buttonshape.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF008AB8"/>
        <stroke android:color="#0299D0"/>
        <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/b_popcorn"></item></layer-list>
```

BlueFragment.xml :

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtePlay" ...
            android:background="@drawable/Buttonshape"
            />
```

Everything is working greate, my button corner is rounded and it apply the drawable, but I have a question :

Is it possible to add more items in my buttonshape.xml and select a specific drawable in my BlueFragment.xml

For example doing something like this :

Buttonshape.xml :

```
...
<item android:drawable="@drawable/b_popcorn"></item></layer-list>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/b_2"></item></layer-list>
```

and in my BlueFragment.xml :

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtePlay" ...
        android:background="@drawable/Buttonshape|b_popcorn"
        />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtePlay2" ...
        android:background="@drawable/Buttonshape|b_2"
        />
```

Something like this to set only one drawable for each button instead of making 50+ xml files for each buttons ...

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a multiple drawable files into your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

we have only option that is using selector, but its only depend on view state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_unchecked" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

so I think we can not do any thing like you expected, so sorry for that !